# Подсветка цвета в PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это Atom Pigments. Как включить аналогичную подсветку цвета в PhpStorm?

Comment: объясните словами что вы понимаете под словом "аналогичную"

Comment: В шторме же сбоку показывает цвет в квадратике, там где нумерация строк.

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan действительно, но почему-то с SVG такого нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите видеть color preview не на полях, а in place, как на скриншоте, попробуйте включить опцию **Show CSS color preview as background** в **Settings | Editor | General | Appearance**